# DVC Shared Windows Directory Setup

Tags: linux, dvc

I have one Linux machine and one Windows machine for developments. For data sharing, we have set up a shared Windows directory in another Windows machine, which both my Linux and Windows can access.

I am now using [DVC](https://dvc.org/) for version control of the shared data. To make it easy, I mount the shared Windows folder both in Windows and in Linux development machine. In Windows, it looks like

```
 [core]
    analytics = false
    remote = remote_storage
['remote "remote_storage"']
    url = \\my_shared_storage\project_dir
```

In Linux, it looks like:

```
[core]
    analytics = false
    remote = remote_storage
['remote "remote_storage"']
    url = /mnt/mount_point/project_dir
```

As you can see, Windows and Linux have different mounting points. So my question is: is there a way to make that both Windows and Linux have the same `ùrl` in the DVC configuration file?

If this is impossible, is there another alternative solution for DVC keeps data in remote shared Windows folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a local remote this way, you won't be able to have to the same `url` on both platforms since the mount points are different (as you already realized).

The simplest way to configure this would be to pick one (Linux or Windows) `url` to use as your default case that gets git-committed into `.dvc/config`. On the other platform you (or your users) can override that `url` in the local configuration file: `.dvc/config.local`.

(Note that `.dvc/config.local` is a git-ignored file and will not be included in any commits)

So if you wanted Windows to be the default case, in `.dvc/config` you would have:

```
 [core]
    analytics = false
    remote = remote_storage
['remote "remote_storage"']
    url = \\my_shared_storage\project_dir
```

and on your Linux machine you would add the file `.dvc/config.local` containing:

```
['remote "remote_storage"']
    url = /mnt/mount_point/project_dir
```

See the DVC docs for `dvc config --local` and `dvc remote modify --local` for more details:

- https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/config#description
- https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/modify#command-options-flags